# Concurrency in CoreData with multiple contexts

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

There are few ways of handling concurrency in CoreData

One of them is using parent/child managedObjectContexts like so:

```
let mainContext = NSManagedObjectContext( concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext( concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)

childContext.parentContext = mainContext
```

Another approach would be to have both the main and child contexts use the same persistentStoreCoordinator like so:

```
let mainContext = NSManagedObjectContext( concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext( concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)

childContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = mainContext.persistentStoreCoordinator
```

Since we'll need to use performBlock on the **childContext** and later save or execute fetch or anything on the **mainContext**, what would be the difference between these two approaches?

I read on [Florian Kugler's blog](http://floriankugler.com/2013/04/29/concurrent-core-data-stack-performance-shootout/) that the former approach processes on the Main Thread (which I tried and it didn't) and the latter is the preferred way. But every other site that I've looked seem to prefer former parent/child context.

To make things more confusing, on RayWenderLich's CoreData book (chapter 10 for references), they've used both of the approaches without explaining why.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally there are 3 simple rule to achieve concurrency in single persistentStore core data application.

1. only one Managed Object context (MOC) should attached with persistentStoreCoordinator is basic rule to avoid MOC lock, unlock on CURD operation.
2. Every MOC should attached with one thread like Main thread MOC, background thread MOC.
3. You can not pass the managed object from one MOC(thread) to other by MOC(thread), in this case just pass ObjectID.

To achieve all three rule, apple introduce parent- child MOC approach. There are so many combination on various post,
But each stack (parent- child MOC approach) is highly depend on the application data usability.

I have implemented as my main MOC contexts use persistentStoreCoordinator, And created background thread child MOC for data synchronisation,
and more local child MOC for each View controller for creating new records screen. this will work well for me and tested with 3500 records insertion on DB. 
The benefit doing this I am getting the updated server sync data through my main MOC.

I know few critics for approach, that I will block the main thread, But you can utilise batch update, delete, asynchronous fetch request to minimise it.

Comment: The thing that blocks main thread is the i/o operation which has to be done on the MainQueue (mainContext). Therefore, batch update will still have the same effect on i/o. And for async fetch requests, since there is one PersistantStoreCoordinator, it will get locked till it finishes CRUD, which will still make the UI blocked. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right. but on data Sync I am calling it inside dispatch_async() block, and it was just main MOC save call, so want be a problem. On other place I did not have any heavy operation. So instead on maintaining 3 level MOC it is worth  value to me.

Comment: Thats why for creating new records I am using temp MOC, which will later save to Main MOC. Three level parent child MOC does not block your main thread but it is slow for batch update and create operation, Each approach have it's prose and cones.All depends on your app behaviour.